# How to launch Android app with HTTP header?

Tags: android, http-headers, google-play

I have seen URL which depending on browser detection has responded with probably some special HTTP header which on Android phone caused to launch Google play application.

So I know its possible, but didn't find info about it, can someone give me some hints where to look for more information ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you:

[Linking to Your Products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)

url should look like this:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to be opened when a certain url is opened in abrowser, you need to add an `IntentFilter` for the url to your `Activity`:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:host="stackoverflow.com"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Will open the activity for any stackoverflow.com url. You can get the actual url in your `Activity` using `getIntent().getData()`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept 2 answers. But I like yours as well, because it gives more detail how to make app which catches certain URLS. Thanks.

Comment: But these two are completely different answers. Did you want to start Google Play or start your app?

Comment: Well, I actually wanted to start my app, but the question was about Google play, so I've decided to mark the other answer. However, yours was more helpful to me.